# How do I make my variables accessible from .py to .kv (kivy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am trying to make a mobile app on the Kivy Framework of Python

I encountered a personal issue, I can't access my variable from my .py file to my .kv file

The app I am trying to make, it scans wifi networks around you and connects to it. So meaning, I have to find a way to access my variables from my .py file to my .kv file (kivy)

I am trying to this: `text: {VARIABLE/FUNCTION HERE FROM .py}`

Here is my code in my **.PY file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
#from wifidroid.wifi import WifiManager
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import kivymd, kivy
#import wifidroid
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

# I WANT TO DISPLAY THESE RESULTS IN MY .KV FILE.. (text:{variables/function})
''' 
wifi = WifiManager()
wifi.startScan()
for i in range(wifi.ScanResults.size()):
ssid = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).SSID]
bssid = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).BSSID]
levell = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).level]
print(ssid[0]+" "+bssid[0]+" "+str(levell[0]))
'''



class Layout_For_App(FloatLayout):
    def test(self, dt):
        self.btn.text = str('Test')
    pass


class AndrdWifiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Layout_For_App()


AndrdWifiApp().run()
```

(*I COMMENTED SOME STUFF, BECAUSE I NEED TO BE ON ANDROID TO TEST*)

Here is my code in my **.KV file**

```
<Layout_For_App>:
    Label:
        text: 'Developed By Anonymous'
        pos_hint: {"x":0,"y":0.45}

    Label:
        text: 'OUTPUT' # I WANT MY WIFI SCANS TO DISPLAY HERE (I NEED VARIABLES FROM .PY OR 
        A FUNCTION)
        background_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
        size_hint: (0.451, 0.7)
        pos_hint: {"x":0.27,"y":0.17}
        valign: "middle"
        halign: "left"
        color: (0,1,0)
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: self.background_color
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        border: 3, 3
    Button:
        text: 'CRACK'
        background_color: 1, 0, 0, 1
        color: 0, 1, 1
        size_hint: (0.4, 0.15)
        pos_hint: {"x":0.0199,"y":0.01}
        font_size: 30

    TextInput:
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.15)
        pos_hint: {'x':0.49,'y':0.01}
        font_size: 40
```

Please help me someone.

**HERE IS A IMAGE OF MY APP:**
[I need the OUTPUT to be the displays of wifi names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMzai.png)

Comment: as I know you can't do it - you have to write code in Python to change text

Comment: maybe you should define variables in `kv` and later assign values to the same `Properties()` in class `Layout_For_App` in `__inti__`

Comment: I would rather add `ID` to `Label` in `kv`  and later in `__init__` I would copy value to `self.ids.label_id.text`

Comment: I checked [documentation for kv](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html) and there is example [Designing with the Kivy Language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#designing-with-the-kivy-language) which define in class `info = StringProperty()` and then it can access it in `kv` as `root.info`. But it has to be `Property` in class, not external variable, and still you would have to run `__init__` to copy value from external variable to `info`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't access variables which are not part of class `Layout_For_App`.

Based on [documentation for kv](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html) and example [Designing with the Kivy Language](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#designing-with-the-kivy-language)

You may have to define variable as `Property` in class

```
class Layout_For_App(FloatLayout):
    
    output = StringProperty()
```

And then you can use it in `kv` using `root.`

```
<Layout_For_App>:

    Label:
        text: 'OUTPUT' + root.output
```

But it needs also to use `__init__` to set value in this variable.

```
wifi = WifiManager()
wifi.startScan()

lines = []
for i in range(wifi.ScanResults.size()):
    ssid  = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).SSID]
    bssid = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).BSSID]
    level = [wifi.ScanResults.get(i).level]
    lines.append( f"{ssid[0]} {bssid[0]} {level[0]}" )

text = "\n".join(lines)

class Layout_For_App(FloatLayout):
    
    output = StringProperty()
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.output = text
```

---

Eventually you should assign `id` to `Label`

```
<Layout_For_App>:

    Label:
        id: label_output
```

and use this `id` in code to set `text`

```
class Layout_For_App(FloatLayout):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.ids.label_output.text = text
```

---

In both versions you have to run code in Python to assign text to this `Label`

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepted, and few minutes later you can upvote it.